# Errors while solving ODE's python

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations, numerical-integration, orbital-mechanics

I have a university project in which we are asked to simulate a satellite approach to Mars using ODE's and SciPy's odeint function.

I manage to simulate it in 2D by making a second-order ODE into two first-order ODE's. However I am stuck in the time limitation because my code is using SI units therefore running in seconds and Python's linspace limits does not even simulate one complete orbit.

I tried converting the variables and constants to hours and kilometers but now the code keeps giving errors.

I followed this method:

http://bulldog2.redlands.edu/facultyfolder/deweerd/tutorials/Tutorial-ODEs.pdf

And the code is:

```
import numpy

import scipy

from scipy.integrate import odeint

def deriv_x(x,t):
    return array([ x[1], -55.3E10/(x[0])**2 ]) #55.3E10 is the value for G*M in km and hours

xinit = array([0,5251]) # this is the velocity for an orbit of period 24 hours

t=linspace(0,24.0,100) 

x=odeint(deriv_x, xinit, t)

def deriv_y(y,t):
    return array([ y[1], -55.3E10/(y[0])**2 ])

yinit = array([20056,0]) # this is the radius for an orbit of period 24 hours

t=linspace(0,24.0,100) 

y=odeint(deriv_y, yinit, t)
```

I don't know how to copy/paste the error code from PyLab so I took a PrintScreen of the error:

[image: Error when running odeint for x]

Second error with t=linspace(0.01,24.0,100) and xinit=array([0.001,5251]):

[image: Second type of error]

If anyone has any suggestions on how to improve the code I will be very grateful.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You will need to show the exact error you are getting.

Comment: I have just edited the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Does it matter that

deriv_x(xinit,0)

is not defined.

Comment: unrelated to your "divide by zero" error, try: `ipython notebook --pylab` or `ipython qtconsole --pylab` to get a nicer interface.

Comment: I changed t to >t=linspace(0.01,24.0,100) and >xinit=array([0.001,5251]) and not I am getting another.

Comment: How your equations look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
odeint(deriv_x, xinit, t)
```

uses `xinit` as its initial guess for `x`. This value for `x` is used when evaluating `deriv_x`.

```
deriv_x(xinit, t)
```

raises a divide-by-zero error since `x[0] = xinit[0]` equals 0, and `deriv_x` divides by `x[0]`.

---

It looks like you are trying to solve the second-order ODE

```
r'' = - C rhat
      ---------
        |r|**2
```

where rhat is the unit vector in the radial direction.

You appear to be separating the `x` and `y` coordinates into separate second-order ODES:

```
x'' = - C             y'' = - C
      -----    and          -----
       x**2                  y**2
```

with initial conditions x0 = 0 and y0 = 20056.

This is very problematic. Among the problems is that when `x0 = 0`, `x''` blows up. The original second-order ODE for `r''` does not have this problem -- the denominator does not blow up when `x0 = 0` because `y0 = 20056`, and so `r0 = (x**2+y**2)**(1/2)` is far from zero.

Conclusion: Your method of separating the `r''` ODE into two ODEs for `x''` and `y''` is incorrect.

Try searching for a different way to solve the `r''` ODE.

Hint:

- What if your "state" vector is `z = [x, y, x', y']`?
- Can you write down a first-order ODE for `z'` in terms of `x`, `y`,
  `x'` and `y'`?
- Can you solve it with *one* call to `integrate.odeint`?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply!
I believe that is exactly the source of the error. However I modified t and xinit as seen on the second image on the original post and I still get an error.
Have you got any suggestion on how to solve this issue?
Sorry for the rather obvious questions, I am very new to Python and programming in general and my course has not been very well taught...
Thanks again!